# Python SQLite Select from Database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

My Database

```
import sqlite3 
conn = sqlite3.connect('Karteikarten.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Karteikarten
#             ([Frage] text, [Antwort] text)''')

F1 = input("Frage: ") A1 = input("Antwort: ")

c.execute('INSERT INTO Karteikarten Values ( ?, ?)', (F1, A1,))
# c.execute('SELECT * FROM Karteikarten')
# print(c.fetchall())

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Now to my question. How can I take the selected input from the database and print it out? I want to compare it with an input from a user later.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Karteikarten.db')

c = conn.cursor()

DBF1 = c.execute('SELECT Frage FROM Karteikarten ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
print(DBF1)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What happens when you print out DBF1?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is fetch output from the database, then you'd use

`foo = c.fetchone()`
or
`foo = c.fetchall()`

to store the output from the database into a variable

You would then `print(foo)`

IE:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Karteikarten.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT Frage FROM Karteikarten ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
DBF1 = c.fetchone() # or c.fetchall()
print(DBF1)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch your result before the print statement.

Change this:

```
DBF1 = c.execute('SELECT Frage FROM Karteikarten ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
```

to this:

```
DBF1 = c.execute('SELECT Frage FROM Karteikarten ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1').fetchall()
```

and  `print(DBF1)` will give you the desired output as a list of tuples